# OG higher w/ full vs. partial boil?

Tags: original-gravity, partial-boil, full-boil

I've done 2 full boils and probably 10 partial boils since I've started homebrewing.  In both full boils, my OG has been significantly higher.   Most recently, by .02 (expected 1.062 measured 1.082).  None of the partial boils were off by this level.

Any thoughts?  Am I extracting more points from the specialty grains with 5g vs. 2g?

Recipe: http://www.northernbrewer.com/documentation/beerkits/BelgianDubbel.pdf

Comment: Can you post the recipe as an example?  20 points is a very large margin.

Comment: Added link to recipe.

Comment: I just realized that recipe is for a partial boil.  Can you tell us the volumes of water you used?  I'll update my answer as appropriate.

Comment: How much wort did you collect at the end of your full boil? Did you add any water to bring it up to 5 gallons?

Comment: Between 4.5 and 4.75 gallons. I measured 1.082 prior to top off.

Comment: Pre-boil volume was a bit over 5 gallons, maybe 5.25.

Comment: @BobBanks:   you should measure *after* top off.

Comment: I did that as well.  Topped off with 1/2g and measured 1.072.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I plugged your recipe into Beersmith, which comes up with a max OG of 1.064, assuming 100% efficiency extracting sugar from the 1/2 lb of specialty grains.

How did you get 1.082?  Guesses:

- Boiled the wort down too far and concentrated it.  You'd have to boil off a whole gallon to get to 1.082, though.
- Hydrometer is bad - calibrate in 60F distilled water to see
- Misreading the hydrometer or miscalculating temperature adjustement
- Bubbles sticking to the hydrometer, raising it up in the test tube
- Weight/volume of ingredients off

Comment: Those are all valid reasons but those things should be equal (except for the 1st) if I'm doing a full vs. partial boil.  I've never been this far off with a partial boil.  Only with the 2 full boils.  Seems odd to me that I'd have these problems on 2 out of 12 boils and both of those were full boil.

Comment: Indeed.  Did you also check the gravity after adding top-up water to 5 gallons?

Comment: Yes, I added 1/2g and it was 1.072.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss.  That is just about the right reading after diluting.  Nothing in the full boil process should change how your sugars are utilized.  At least not that I know of.

Comment: I don't have any explanation either, but it will be interesting to see what the final gravity is. A starting gravity of 1.084 would yields a terminal gravity no lower than 1.020 (75% apparent attenuation), I think (for an all malt brew). If the terminal gravity is significantly lower than this, we might want to conclude that the original gravity reading was wrong.

Comment: That would be a difficult conclusion, as your pre- and post-dilution readings make sense in relation to each other.  Have you tried calibrating the hydrometer, just for giggles?

Comment: @JoeFish I have not, but I'll give it a shot.  I believe I have an old gallon jug of distilled water around here somewhere.  I may pick up a refractometer since I can use it for the saltwater tank too.

Comment: @TobiasPatton I ended up topping off to bring the OG down to 1.062.  Not sure if that was the best course of action...

Answer (score 1):

When I go to my local HBS to get a kit made up, I have noticed that they do their best not to short me on ingredients but typically over it, sometimes by quite a bit. I assume that you got your kit from northern brewer but I can’t imagine that they don’t do something similar. Did you happen to weigh out you ingredients before you boiled?

Comment: Nope, but I'll do that on my next couple batches to see.